# Plot diagram in Pandas from CSV without headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to plotting charts in python. I've been told to use Pandas for that, using the following command. Right now it is assumed the `csv` file has headers (`time`,`speed`, etc). But how can I change it to when the `csv` file doesn't have headers? (data starts from row 0)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.read_csv("P1541350772737.csv")
#df.head(5)
df.plot(figsize=(15,5), kind='line',x='timestamp', y='speed') # scatter plot
```

Comment: Skip the plotting for the moment, and focus on what `pandas` loads.  Look at the `df`.  Seek to understand how it labels rows and columns.

Comment: yes, definitely I need to learn it. Any preference to use matplotlib for plotting instead of Panda's own plot?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may havve missinterpreted your question but II'll do my best.

Th problem seems to be that you have to read a csv that have no header but you want to add them. I would use this code:

```
cols=['time', 'speed', 'something', 'else'] 
df = pd.read_csv('useful_data.csv', names=cols, header=None)
```

For your plot, the code you used should be fine with my correction. I would also suggest to look at *matplotlib* in order to do your graph.

Comment: does the `cols` length need to match with the total number of columns in the csv?! It doesn't work right now.

Comment: Yes, it must match

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have to match!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify x and y by the index of the columns, you don't need names of the columns for that:

Very simple: `df.plot(figsize=(15,5), kind='line',x=0, y=1)`

It works if `x` column is first and `y` column is second and so on, columns are numerated from `0`

For example:

[image]

The same result with the names of the columns instead of positions:
[image]

Comment: How can I pass only the index?! This will be simple!

Comment: I added to the answer

Comment: ummm it doesn't work for me! `x=0` simply shows a (0,1) line!

Comment: it depends on what you want to plot. `x=0` just indicates that the column that comes first should be on the x axis. If this column had a name you could write it's name instead of it's index (i.e. position). Note that if you plot with `kind='line'` at least one of columns (`x` or `y`) have to be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df  = pd.read_csv("P1541350772737.csv", header=None)
```

with the `names`-kwarg you can set arbitrary column headers, this implies silently `headers=None`, i.e. reading data from row 0.

You might also want to check the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Then how to specify x and y?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is more focused on data structures and data analysis tools, it actually supports plotting by using [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) as backend. If you're interested in building different types of plots in Python you might want to check it out.

Back to Pandas, Pandas assumes that the first row of your csv is a header. However, if your file doesn't have a header you can pass `header=None` as a parameter `pd.read_csv("P1541350772737.csv", header=None)` and then plot it as you are doing it right now.

The full list of commands that you can pass to Pandas for reading a csv can be found at [Pandas read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), you'll find a lot of useful commands there (such as skipping rows, defining the index column, etc.)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

For most commands you will find help in the respective documentation. Looking at [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll find an argument `names`

> `names` : array-like, default None
>    List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly 
>    pass header=None.

So you will want to give your columns names by which they appear in the dataframe.

As an example: Suppose you have this data file

```
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
```

Then you can do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", names=["A", "B"], header=None)
print(df)
df.plot(x="A", y="B")

plt.show()
```

which outputs

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

[image]

Comment: does it matter to delete `plt.show()`?! Looks like no changes!

Comment: This totally depends on where and how you run the code. Some programs call that automatically for you so to speak.